# Custom ECB-Menu Item which copies the Link of the document into the Clipboard

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, item, ecb-menu

I would like to add an Item to the Edit Control Block Menu (ECB-Menu) (red marked in Screenshot), which copies when clicking on this Item (onClick) the link of the chosen document into the Clipboard. I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I neither have SharePoint Designer nor Top-Level-Site-Owner rights. I also don't have Visual Studios. That's why I am searching for a solution with Script Editor (or Content Editor) Web Part.

[image]

**Update:** My Code looks like this currently:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx)
    {
      var strDisplayText = "New entry";
      var strAction = "window.open('http://google.com', '_self')";
      var strImagePath = "";

      // Add our new menu item
      CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath, strDisplayText.link);

      // add a separator to the menu
      CAMSep(m);

      // false means that the standard menu items should also be rendered
      return false;
    }
    </script>
```

The new inserted Item can open a link. Now I would like to replace this strAction with the function for copying the link of the chosen document into the clipboard.

Comment: It would be also okay, to only show the link to copy manually

Comment: I think you would find many answers on how to copy some content in user's clipboard at StackOverflow.SE!

Comment: Thanks for your hint Nisarg, will try to find there sth. :)

Comment: Following Code can embed an URL, how it is displayed in the Callout Menu:
<input onblur="javascript: this.value = this.defaultValue;" onclick="javascript: this.select();" class="js-callout-location" value="LINK" id="co107,3,0_calloutSourceUrl">

Comment: What web browsers and versions do you need to support?

Comment: Hello Mihail, thanks for your comment. It should support at least Internet Explorer Version 10 and newer and optionally Chrome as addition.

Comment: I used clipboard.min.js for a custom hover panel in my search results to get the list item link into the clipboard. Maybe you can check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar requirement sometime ago.

Due to [browser compatibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery), I ended up using [window.prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp), shifting the control of the copy/paste functionality over to the user:

```
window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
```

BTW, the text will already be selected, so the user simply has to press CTRL+C.

At the time I believe this is where I got the idea from:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

**EDIT**

The (very rough) code below will do as asked:

Create a custom action, when clicked, display the link to the document.

Alternatively, you can use some additional tweaking to actually save the link into the clipboard. Some apis are referenced in the Stack Overflow link above, though they may not support all the browsers.

```
console.log("hello world");

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185004%28v=office.14%29.aspx#sectionSection0

var webUrl = "/sites/a/b/c";
var actionTitle = "My First User Custom Action";
var listTitle = "Procedures";//consider using context.ListTitle if available

//potentially use these to grab the current url automatically
function getWebUrl()
{
    return _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
}
function getSiteUrl() {
    return _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
}

function createUserCustomActionList() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);

    //var listTitle = clientContext.ListTitle;

    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var collUserCustomAction = oList.get_userCustomActions();

    var oUserCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.add();
    oUserCustomAction.set_sequence(100);
    oUserCustomAction.set_title(actionTitle);

    oUserCustomAction.set_location('EditControlBlock');

    //oUserCustomAction.set_url(webUrl + '/_layouts/MyPage.aspx?id={ItemUrl}');

    //use ItemUrl property to grab the url of the selected item (also available, ItemID).
    //using function instead of redirect
    //consider using other apis to automatically store in the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript
    oUserCustomAction.set_url("javascript:var link = '{ItemUrl}'; window.prompt('here you go', link);");

    /*
    failed attempts :)
    oUserCustomAction.set_location('ScriptLink');
    //oUserCustomAction.set_scriptSrc(webUrl + '/js/click.js');
    oUserCustomAction.set_scriptBlock = "\
    \
        function JSFX_StartEffects()\
        {\
            JSFX.Fire(200, 100, 100);\
        }\
        var windowOnload=window.onload||function(){};window.onload=function(){JSFX_StartEffects();};\
    \
    ";
    */

    oUserCustomAction.update();

    clientContext.load(oList, 'Title' ,'UserCustomActions');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
        //success
        console.log("success");
    }

    ),

         Function.createDelegate(this, function(a, b){
            //error
            console.log("error:" + b.get_message());
         }

         ));

}

function deleteUserCustomAction() {

    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(webUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    this.collUserCustomAction = oList.get_userCustomActions();

    clientContext.load(oList,'UserCustomActions','Title');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function()
    {
        //success
        console.log("custom actions loaded");       

        var customActionEnumerator = collUserCustomAction.getEnumerator();

        while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext()) 
        {
            var oUserCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();

            if (oUserCustomAction.get_title() == actionTitle) 
            {

                //will throw "collection updated" exception after, but will delete the action
                oUserCustomAction.deleteObject();

                clientContext.load(oUserCustomAction);

                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
                    //success
                    console.log("custom action deleted");
                }

                ),

                 Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
                    //error
                    console.log("error deleting custom action");
                 }

                 ))

            }
        }

    }

    ),

     Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
        //error
        console.log("error loading custom actions");
     }

     ));

}


//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createUserCustomActionList, 'sp.js'); 

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){

    //delete custom action - in case code is executed more than once, delete the action, then recreate it
    deleteUserCustomAction();

    //create custom action
    createUserCustomActionList();
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. So to combine your response with my requirement I would have to display somehow the URL of the document, after clicking on the new inserted entry of the ECB-Menu. I've currently no idea how this works, so could you help me please in that?

Comment: Thank you very much mate. You can't imagine how hard you helped me. I can give you the bounty in 15 hours, so the points will be yours :)

Comment: One more little question: what do I have to replace in the Code after inserting? And to what the link should point to?

Comment: Hello Tiago, I got one more question. Sometimes it's the case, that suddenly the item is standing more than once in the actiom list. And then I have to remove the doubled entry again. I wanted to know where this "bug" might come from - if you have any idea

Comment: the code is supposed to be executed once, not on every page load.

Answer (score 2):

Add this below given code in a  **CEWP** (Content Editor Web Part).

```
<script language="javascript">
function Custom_AddDocLibMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
var strDisplayText = Redirect to form here;
var strImagePath = ;
var strAction = 'window.navigate(/.../editform.aspx?Source= document.URL.substring(0, document.URL.indexOf(/Forms, 0)) ?RootFolder= GetUrlKeyValue(RootFolder)) DocUrl= GetDocURL(ctx)';
// Add our new menu item
CAMOpt(m, strDisplayText, strAction, strImagePath);
// add a separator to the menu
CAMSep(m);
// false means that the standard menu items should also be rendered
return false;
}
function string GetDocURL(ctx)
{
var URL = ;
var index = itemTable.innerHTML.indexOf(href=);
if (index 0)
{
var str = itemTable.innerHTML.substr(index 6);
index = str.indexOf('');
if (index 0)
{
URL = str.substr(0, index);
}
}
return URL;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Hardik. What do I have to replace after inserting this Code, cuz just after simply adding it it doesn't change my ECB Menu

Comment: Yes of course it will not change... You need to change the variables for strDisplayText & strAction.

Comment: to the strAction: Do I have to insert link to the document library in front of the editForm? Sorry but I'm kinda a rookie in that :)

Comment: No you don't need to specify anything into that

Comment: Thanks. And so how do I have to change the variables? I currently don't really know how it should look. I'm sorry for my annoying questions :)

Comment: Sorry my mistake... You do not need to specify anything in strImagePath... Yes you are right... You need to add document url in strAction but mine will also work...let know what will you get as output... I will help you further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41138/discussion-between-steffpoint-and-hardik).

Comment: Did you find sth. Hardik?

Answer (score 1):

You can add **Custom Action** for list items using JavaScript. You have to set the appropriate document URL as a link.

- [Adding a User Custom Action for List Items Using Javascript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185004%28v=office.14%29.aspx#sectionSection0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Could you help me please to help me creating a Custom Action for my requirement, because I personally have no idea how I could get the URL of the chosen document.